# $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$ is a splitting field of $f_{\mathbb{Q}}^{i+\sqrt{2}} $ and $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})) \cong V_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, automorphism-group

So hi all, I'm trying to show that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}))$ is isomorphic to $V_4$ but I don't have enough intuition for this yet to solve it. Would you like to give me some advice? Thanks in advance. And sorry if someone else asked this question already; I couldn't find it.

What I've found already is that $f_{\mathbb{Q}}^{i+\sqrt{2}} = X^{4} - 2X^{2} + 9$ and I think that this yields that $\mathbb{Q}(-i-\sqrt{2},-i+\sqrt{2},i-\sqrt{2},i+\sqrt{2}) = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}). $

Comment: I think you mean field automorphism with ground field $Q$ fixed here. It is galois group with action on $i$ and $i\to -i$ or fixing $i$. And $\sqrt{2}\to -\sqrt{2}$ or fixing it. Now you have to show $Q(i)\not\cong Q(\sqrt{2})$ which will show that the two morphism do not see each other. You know it is galois as it is a splitting field a polynomial. Then the number of morphism is exactly 4. And each non-trivial element has order 2 which you can check by hand.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me some extra direction. We should be able to solve it without Galois theory though (since I haven't had that yet).

Comment: Or, more concretely: I don't see how you got to know the number of morphisms is exactly 4.

Comment: Oh and your first expressed thought was right, sorry for the incomplete question.